# Collection.findOne({_id: "stringidsdfdsfdsfds"}) is returns undefined

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-react

I'm not new to Meteor, but been away for a couple of weeks due to working on other projects.

I'm now working on a Meteor project using React.

When I do this `Collection.find({}).fetch()` it returns this:

```
[
  {
       "_id": { "_str": "59d3b91d80f4f5eeb0162634" },
       "title": "My first Post",
       "content": "This is the body of the pst"
  }
]
```

The only strange thing is the `_id` field.

But, when I do `Collection.findOne({_id: "59d3b91d80f4f5eeb0162634" })`, it returns `undefined`.

How can I do a `.findOne()` using the `_id` string as query parameter?

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing as `_id`'s value is not a JSON object, but string representation of Mongo's `ObjectID` type, that's why your `.findOne()` fails to find it.

You should search it like this:

```js
const _id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID('59d3b91d80f4f5eeb0162634');
Collection.findOne({ _id }); // same as { _id: _id }
```

By default, Meteor [uses `STRING` method of `_id` generation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html), so it seems that this particular document has been inserted into collection another way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I actually inserted it from the `meteor mongo` console.

Comment: @Kenshinman I recommend you to use `meteor shell` console for something like this.